# How to integrate native blackberry 10 or wikitude SDK with webworks?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-cascades, wikitude, blackberry-ndk

I am working on a BB 10 app using Webworks . I have almost completed it but the clients want to implement wikitude SDK for AR . But it only provide SDk for native blackberry 10 . Is there a way to implement wikitude with Webwork . Or a way to implement native code in webworks?

Answer (score 2):

We have not tested or tried using Webworks together with the Wikitude SDK. However our phonegap and titanium plugins (available on github) are built on top of our regular Android and iOS SDK. Without knowing the internals of Webworks I think opening a native View on top of Webworks that runs the SDK should be possible.

Disclaimer: I work for Wikitude.

Comment: But the phonegap built includes some lib files for android like jar files . I think we would need some kind of lib for blackberry also. Please give some solution to this I have invested too much and now I cannot rewrite the code in native.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is exactly what you've suggested in the comment to @wulfgeng's answer. The wikitude cordova plugin for 3.x+ would need to be updated to add a native component for BlackBerry10 (or you could write your own native plugin).